# How can I load a specific codenameone Form every time the app is open?

Tags: java, eclipse, codenameone

I can't troubleshoot this with the simulator since there's no home button in it like in a phone.

I will like to load a specific Form based on certain parameters every time the app is reopen. How can I accomplished this?

Answer (score 1):

Just stop the simulator and run it over again. If you want to simulate "backgrounding" (minimize) then just use the suspend/resume functionality of the simulator.

Comment: I don't see any suspend/resume functionality in the simulator, I can see "Pause" which I tried, but doesn't seem to simulate "backgrounding"

Comment: Pause calls stop() and resuming calls start() again which is exactly what happens when the app is minimized.

Comment: I understood the functionality of stop() and start(). Now, the issue that I have is that I can't get the specific form so that I can set "current" form (MyApplication.java), to be a specific one from GUI. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The current form is set in stop() I'm assuming you have a GUI builder application? If so you can replace the usage of current with a String destinationForm and set it to something other than null in stop. Then in start if destination form is not null just use showForm(destinationForm, null) on the state machine object.